# canonical problems list

Tags: reference, theory, knapsack-problem

Does anyone known of a a good reference for canonical CS problems?

I'm thinking of things like "the sorting problem", "the bin packing problem", "the travailing salesman problem" and what not.

**edit:** websites preferred

Answer (score 4):

You can probably find the best in an algorithms textbook like [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937). Though I've never read that particular book, it's quite renowned for being thorough and would probably contain most of the problems you're likely to encounter.

Answer (score 4):

["Computers and Intractability: A guide to the theory of NP-Completeness"](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=578533) by Garey and Johnson is a great reference for this sort of thing, although the "solved" problems (in P) are obviously not given much attention in the book.

I'm not aware of any good on-line resources, but Karp's seminal paper [Reducibility among Combinatorial Problems (1972)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems) on reductions and complexity is probably the "canonical" reference for Hard Problems.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Wikipedia's [Category:Computational problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computational_problems) and [Category:NP Complete Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:NP-complete_problems) pages? It's probably not complete, but they look like good starting points. Wikipedia seems to do pretty well in CS topics.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll find the answers to all those problems in only one book. I've never seen any decent, comprehensive website on algorithms, so I'd recommend you to stick to the books. That said, you can always get some introductory material on canonical algorithm texts (there are always three I usually recommend: [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937), [Manber](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201120372), [Aho, Hopcroft and Ullman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201000296) (this one is a bit out of date in some key topics, but it's so formal and well-written that it's a must-read). All of them contain important combinatorial problems that are, in some sense, canonical problems in computer science. After learning some fundamentals in graph theory you'll be able to move to Network Flows and Linear Programming. These comprise a set of techniques that will ultimately solve most problems you'll encounter (linear programming with the variables restricted to integer values is NP-hard). Network flows deals with problems defined on graphs (with weighted/capacitated edges) with very interesting applications in fields that seemingly have no relationship to graph theory whatsoever. THE textbook on this is [Ahuja, Magnanti and Orlin's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013617549X). Linear programming is some kind of superset of network flows, and deals with optimizing a linear function on variables subject to restrictions in the form of a linear system of equations. A book that emphasizes the relationship to network flows is [Bazaraa's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471485993). Then you can move on to integer programming, a very valuable tool that presents many natural techniques for modelling problems like bin packing, task scheduling, the knapsack problem, and so on. A good reference would be [L. Wolsey's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471283665) book.

Comment: Note: I'm more looking for the list of Problems than the list of Solutions. Good answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You **definitely** want to look at NIST's [Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](http://www.nist.gov/dads/). It's got the [traveling salesman problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/travelingSalesman.html), the [Byzantine generals problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/byzantine.html), the [dining philosophers' problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/diningphilos.html), the [knapsack problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/knapsackProblem.html) (= your "bin packing problem", I think), the [cutting stock problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/cuttingStock.html), the [eight queens problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/eightqueens.html), the [knight's tour problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/knightstour.html), the [busy beaver problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/busyBeaver.html), the [halting problem](http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/haltingProblem.html), etc. etc.

It doesn't have the [firing squad synchronization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firing_squad_synchronization_problem) (I'm surprised about that omission) or the [Jeep problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JeepProblem.html) (more logistics than computer science).

Interestingly enough there's a blog on [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000951.html) which talks about some of these in puzzle form. (I can't remember whether I've read Smullyan's book cited in the blog, but he is a good compiler of puzzles & philosophical musings. Martin Gardner and Douglas Hofstadter and [H.E. Dudeney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Dudeney) are others.)

Also maybe check out the [Stony Brook Algorithm Repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/).

(Or look up "combinatorial problems" on google, or search for "problem" in [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/index.html?query=problem) or look at [Hilbert's problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_problems), but in all these links many of them are more pure-mathematics than computer science.)

Comment: bin packing is a like knapsack but you put everything in and minimize the bin count

Answer (score 0):

@rcreswick those sound like good references but fall a bit shy of what I'm thinking of. (However, for all I know, it's the best there is)

I'm going to not mark anything as accepted in hopes people might find a better reference.

Meanwhile, I'm going to list a few problems here, fell free to add more

**The sorting problem** Find an order for a set that is monotonic in a given way

**The bin packing problem** partition a set into a minimum number of sets where each subset is "smaller" than some limit

**The travailing salesman problem** Find a Hamiltonian cycle in a weighted graph with the minimum total weight